# Pegar valor de um atributo dentro de um input de uma coluna da tabela

Tags: jquery, html5

Eu tenho uma tabela e esta tabela tem uma coluna que tem um input do tipo checkbox. Nesse input eu criei um atributo. Como faço para percorrer essa coluna e recuperar o valor do atributo?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>BVeículos</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead class="f quinze quase-preto fundo-thead">
   <tr>
         <th class="larg-10">Marca</th>
   <th class="larg-10">Modelo</th>
   <th class="larg-10">Teste Driver?</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tr>
<td>Fiat</td>
<td>Uno</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  VeiculoId="1">Fazer teste</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ford</td>
<td>KA</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  VeiculoId="2">Fazer teste</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GM</td>
<td>Corsa</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  VeiculoId="3">Fazer teste</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button>Agendar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria interessante criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para demonstrar o seu problema

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jQuery você inicialmente faz uma seleção de DOM nas colunas, algo como:

```
$("table.table tr td input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, element){
    var atributo = $(this).attr("VeiculoId");
});
```

Vale ressaltar que um dos padrões mais utilizados no HTML 5 é o uso do attrbuto `data-*` que no seu caso seria `data-VeiculoId`. Para esse padrão existe uma função específica do jQuery: a `.data()`. Nesse caso ficaria:

```
$("table.table tr td input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, element){
    var atributo = $(this).data("VeiculoId");
});
```

Note que esse seletor para chegar ao input não é muito performático. Sugiro que adicione uma classe ao td da tabela, encurtando assim a seleção. Algo como `<td class="check">`. Desse modo o seu seletor ficaria algo como: `$(".check input[type=checkbox]")`

Referências:
1. https://api.jquery.com/data/
2. https://api.jquery.com/each/
3. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

Que tal com Javascript puro?

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td input");
for(let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
  console.log(checkbox[i].getAttribute('VeiculoId'));
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>BVeículos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="f quinze quase-preto fundo-thead">
            <tr>
                <th class="larg-10">Marca</th>
                <th class="larg-10">Modelo</th>
                <th class="larg-10">Teste Driver?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiat</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" VeiculoId="1">Fazer teste</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>KA</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" VeiculoId="2">Fazer teste</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GM</td>
            <td>Corsa</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" VeiculoId="3">Fazer teste</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```